# Simple Javascript rectangle area function

Tags: javascript

I'm writing a simple function to calculate the area of a rectangle...

Here is my code:

```
<form id="rectangleForm" method="post">
<h1>Calculate the area of a rectangle:</h1>
<div>
    <label for="width">Width</label> 
    <input type="text" name="width" id="width" value="1.00" />
</div>
<div>
    <label for="height">Height</label>
    <input type="text" name="height" id="height" value="1.00"/>
</div>
<div>
    <label for="area">Area</label>
    <input type="text" name="area" id="rectarea" value="0.00" />
</div>
<div>
    <input type="submit" value="Calculate" id="submit" />
</div>

</form>
<script>

function rectangle() {
'use strict';
var area;
var width = document.getElementById('width').value;
var height = document.getElementById('height').value;
total = width * height;
document.getElementById('area').value = total;
return false;
}          

function init() {
   'use strict';
   var rectangleForm = document.getElementById('rectangleForm');
   rectangleForm.onsubmit = rectangle();
}

window.onload = init();
</script>
```

I'm getting an "uncaught typeError: cannot read the property 'value' of null." error on the var width line. I don't understand why. Can anyone shed any details or solutions?

Answer (score 3):

There are three problems in your code.

Firstly, on the following lines:

```
rectangleForm.onsubmit = rectangle();

window.onload = init();
```

...you are *calling* the `rectangle()` and `init()` functions and assigning their results as the `onsubmit` and `onload` handler, which means the functions are run once straight away and not run in response to the form submission event. You need to remove the parentheses so that the functions themselves get assigned as handlers:

```
rectangleForm.onsubmit = rectangle;

window.onload = init;
```

Secondly, your area input has `id="rectarea"` but in your code you use `document.getElementById("area")` - you need to match these up.

Thirdly, your functions have the `'use strict';` directive, but then your code isn't actually strict because you don't declare the `total` variable. So change:

```
total = width * height;
```

to:

```
var total = width * height;
```

With those changes applied your code works as shown in this demo: http://jsbin.com/avimac/1/edit

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working fiddle of your script:

http://jsfiddle.net/sBRr7/2/

EDITED: Based on the additional comments by nnnnnn I updated mine aswell (although his answer is more explanatory)

Removed the post:

```
<form id="rectangleForm">
```

Fixed the id of the input:

```
<input type="text" name="area" id="area" value="0.00" />
```

Changed the input type to button:

```
<input type="button" value="Calculate" id="submit" />
```

Added variable declaration:

```
var total = width * height;
```

Changed the init function:

```
    var submit = document.getElementById('submit');
    submit.onclick = rectangle;
```

Changed the onload handler:

```
window.onload = init;
```

Comment: _"There were several issues with it:"_ - Which you _didn't_ fix. You just left (several of) the problems there and ignored them by adding an inline `onclick` handler to the submit button.

Comment: While you were commenting I was already updating my answer as I noticed this "several issues" won't be very helpful - thanks :)

Comment: In regards to the inline handler - sure on could add a submit handler aswell but my guess is that user2281178 is looking for a quick and working solution ... and maybe not for the most sexy js code ;)

Comment: The OP _already has_ an onsubmit handler that they are trying to assign in their code. So a "quick and working solution" would be to fix the minor mistake in that part of their code and then fix the id of the area input.

Answer (score 0):

First the obvious error here is that u have to assign a reference to onload and onsubmit functions and not execute the functions. Like this...

```
windows.onload = init;
```

And also ...

```
rectangleFom.onSubmit = rectangle;
```

Try after fixing these errors.

Comment: removed both parentheses and also noticed an error in the "total = width*height" line... should've been area not total, but it still doesn't work. I input values and it doesn't calculate.

Comment: I did the same thing and it worked. Check out this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sBRr7/)

Answer (score 0):

Only 3 things to fix in your code, working copy here: http://tests.dev.activisual.net/test2.html

1. Remove 'Use String'; That does nothing and in chrome it crashes the code.
2. Don't call the function before assigning it to the event (because the function gets executed instead of assigned), so instead of `rectangleForm.onsubmit = rectangle();` use `rectangleForm.onsubmit = rectangle;`
3. Be more carefull when calling your ids. Your result box is not called "area" is called "rectarea", so change `getElementById('area')` to `getElementById('rectarea')`.

Comment: It's `'use strict';`, not `'Use String;'`, and it causes a problem because the code in the function doesn't follow strict rules, so the way to fix it is to fix that part, not to remove the strict directive.